# Get correct click position on scaled image

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I get the click position when clicking on an image to do some image transformation. But my problem is, that the image has the CSS attribute `max-width: 1000px`. So the code works only for images which are smaller. For larger images the position result is not the real pixel which was clicked on.

My question is, if it is possible to calculate the correct click position for the natural sized image. An alternative would be to set some data attributes with the real image size like `data-width: '1200px'` and `data-height: '1000px'`. But still I have to do some calculation.

```
parentPosition = getPosition(event.currentTarget),
x = event.clientX - parentPosition.x,
y = event.clientY - parentPosition.y;

function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

Comment: No need to use `data-width` / `data-height` you can get `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` from image. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know natural size and current size, i think you can just do this:

```
naturalClickPosX = (naturalWidth / currentWidth) * currentClickPosX;

naturalClickPosY = (naturalHeight / currentHeight) * currentClickPosY;
```

Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/ddewpf3k/1/) JSFiddle

HTML

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1200x1000" width="1000">
```

JavaScript

```
$('img').on("click", function(e){
    var $img = $(this);
    var currentClickPosX = e.pageX - $img.offset().left;
    var currentClickPosY = e.pageY - $img.offset().top;

    var currentWidth = $img.width();
    var currentHeight = $img.height();

    var naturalWidth = this.naturalWidth;
    var naturalHeight = this.naturalHeight;

    var naturalClickPosX = ((naturalWidth / currentWidth) * currentClickPosX).toFixed(0);
    var naturalClickPosY = ((naturalHeight / currentHeight) * currentClickPosY).toFixed(0);

    alert("Current X: " + currentClickPosX + " Current Y: " + currentClickPosY + 
          "\r\nNatural X: " + naturalClickPosX + " Natural Y: " + naturalClickPosY);
});
```

Comment: Just for better understanding: What if I need the opposite thing? If I have a naturalPosition for a point and I want to show that on the sized image? I'm asking because I save the naturalPosition in the DB and display a element as absolute positioning over the image. But if the image is sized, the position is not correct.

Comment: Instead, divide sizedSize with naturalSize and multiply with naturalPosition. Like this: `sizedPosX = (sizedWidth / naturalWidth) * naturalPosX`. This is just math btw, using `ratios`.

Comment: In this specific example, taking the width (1200 natural, 1000 sized), the natural size is bigger by a factor of `1.2` (1200/1000). Hence, we multiply the value we got from the click with `1.2`. `sizedPosX * 1.2` is what we want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to write a function with a parameter to get the value which is needed (dividing or multipliply).

Comment: how can we get click position is percentage?